Помогите с paper сервером
сервер не работает
LOG:

E:\server 1.21.1>java -Xms4G -Xmx4G -jar server.jar --nogui
Starting org.bukkit.craftbukkit.Main
[17:08:01 INFO]: [bootstrap] Running Java 21 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 21.0.4+7-LTS; Amazon.com Inc. Corretto-21.0.4.7.1) on Windows 11 10.0 (amd64)
[17:08:01 INFO]: [bootstrap] Loading Paper 1.21.1-69-master@925c3b9 (2024-09-07T20:43:21Z) for Minecraft 1.21.1
[17:08:02 INFO]: [PluginInitializerManager] Initializing plugins...
[17:08:02 INFO]: [PluginInitializerManager] Initialized 9 plugins
[17:08:02 INFO]: [PluginInitializerManager] Bukkit plugins (9):
 - AuthMe (5.7.0-FORK-b53), BannerMaker (2.5.0), Essentials (2.21.0-dev+111-b54c8c1), EssentialsChat (2.21.0-dev+111-b54c8c1), EssentialsProtect (2.21.0-dev+111-b54c8c1), EssentialsSpawn (2.21.0-dev+111-b54c8c1), LuckPerms (5.4.141), NoChatReports (2.1.0), ViaVersion (5.0.3)
[17:08:05 INFO]: Environment: Environment[sessionHost=https://sessionserver.mojang.com, servicesHost=https://api.minecraftservices.com, name=PROD]
[17:08:06 INFO]: Loaded 1290 recipes
[17:08:06 INFO]: Loaded 1399 advancements
[17:08:07 INFO]: Starting minecraft server version 1.21.1
[17:08:07 INFO]: Loading properties
[17:08:07 INFO]: This server is running Paper version 1.21.1-69-master@925c3b9 (2024-09-07T20:43:21Z) (Implementing API version 1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT)
[17:08:07 INFO]: [spark] This server bundles the spark profiler. For more information please visit https://docs.papermc.io/paper/profiling
[17:08:07 INFO]: Using 4 threads for Netty based IO
[17:08:07 INFO]: Server Ping Player Sample Count: 12
[17:08:08 INFO]: [ChunkTaskScheduler] Chunk system is using 1 I/O threads, 3 worker threads, and population gen parallelism of 3 threads
[17:08:08 INFO]: Default game type: SURVIVAL
[17:08:08 INFO]: Generating keypair
[17:08:08 INFO]: Starting Minecraft server on localhost:25565
[17:08:08 INFO]: Using default channel type
[17:08:08 INFO]: Paper: Using Java compression from Velocity.
[17:08:08 INFO]: Paper: Using Java cipher from Velocity.
[17:08:09 WARN]: [org.bukkit.craftbukkit.legacy.CraftLegacy] Initializing Legacy Material Support. Unless you have legacy plugins and/or data this is a bug!
[17:08:14 WARN]: Legacy plugin LuckPerms v5.4.141 does not specify an api-version.
[17:08:15 INFO]: [ViaVersion] Loading server plugin ViaVersion v5.0.3
[17:08:15 INFO]: [ViaVersion] ViaVersion 5.0.3 is now loaded. Registering protocol transformers and injecting...
[17:08:15 INFO]: [ViaVersion] Loading block connection mappings ...
[17:08:15 INFO]: [ViaVersion] Using FastUtil Long2ObjectOpenHashMap for block connections
[17:08:16 INFO]: [LuckPerms] Loading server plugin LuckPerms v5.4.141
[17:08:16 INFO]: [Essentials] Loading server plugin Essentials v2.21.0-dev+111-b54c8c1
[17:08:16 INFO]: [EssentialsSpawn] Loading server plugin EssentialsSpawn v2.21.0-dev+111-b54c8c1
[17:08:16 INFO]: [NoChatReports] Loading server plugin NoChatReports v2.1.0
[17:08:16 WARN]: [NoChatReports] [packetevents] We currently do not support the minecraft version 1.21.1, so things might break. PacketEvents will behave as if the minecraft version were 1.21.0!
[17:08:18 INFO]: [EssentialsProtect] Loading server plugin EssentialsProtect v2.21.0-dev+111-b54c8c1
[17:08:18 INFO]: [EssentialsChat] Loading server plugin EssentialsChat v2.21.0-dev+111-b54c8c1
[17:08:18 INFO]: [BannerMaker] Loading server plugin BannerMaker v2.5.0
[17:08:18 INFO]: [AuthMe] Loading server plugin AuthMe v5.7.0-FORK-b53
[17:08:18 INFO]: Server permissions file permissions.yml is empty, ignoring it
[17:08:18 INFO]: [LuckPerms] Enabling LuckPerms v5.4.141*
[17:08:18 INFO]:         __
[17:08:18 INFO]:   |    |__)   LuckPerms v5.4.141
[17:08:18 INFO]:   |___ |      Running on Bukkit - Paper
[17:08:18 INFO]:
[17:08:18 INFO]: [LuckPerms] Loading configuration...
[17:08:18 INFO]: [LuckPerms] Loading storage provider... [H2]
[17:08:19 INFO]: [LuckPerms] Loading internal permission managers...
[17:08:19 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling LuckPerms v5.4.141 (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: me/lucko/luckperms/lib/guava/graph/MutableGraph
        at me.lucko.luckperms.bukkit.util.PluginManagerUtil.injectDependency(PluginManagerUtil.java:63) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.bukkit.LPBukkitPlugin.setupPlatformHooks(LPBukkitPlugin.java:224) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.common.plugin.AbstractLuckPermsPlugin.enable(AbstractLuckPermsPlugin.java:225) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.bukkit.LPBukkitBootstrap.onEnable(LPBukkitBootstrap.java:175) ~[?:?]
        at LuckPerms-Bukkit-Legacy-5.4.141.jar/me.lucko.luckperms.bukkit.loader.BukkitLegacyLoaderPlugin.onEnable(BukkitLegacyLoaderPlugin.java:50) ~[LuckPerms-Bukkit-Legacy-5.4.141.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:288) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginInstanceManager.enablePlugin(PaperPluginInstanceManager.java:202) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.enablePlugin(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:109) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:520) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:640) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:589) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:293) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1215) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:330) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[?:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: me.lucko.luckperms.lib.guava.graph.MutableGraph
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:593) ~[?:?]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[?:?]
        ... 15 more
[17:08:19 INFO]: [LuckPerms] Disabling LuckPerms v5.4.141
[17:08:19 INFO]: [LuckPerms] Starting shutdown process...
[17:08:19 ERROR]: Error occurred while disabling LuckPerms v5.4.141
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "me.lucko.luckperms.common.extension.SimpleExtensionManager.close()" because "this.extensionManager" is null
        at me.lucko.luckperms.common.plugin.AbstractLuckPermsPlugin.disable(AbstractLuckPermsPlugin.java:284) ~[?:?]
        at me.lucko.luckperms.bukkit.LPBukkitBootstrap.onDisable(LPBukkitBootstrap.java:191) ~[?:?]
        at LuckPerms-Bukkit-Legacy-5.4.141.jar/me.lucko.luckperms.bukkit.loader.BukkitLegacyLoaderPlugin.onDisable(BukkitLegacyLoaderPlugin.java:55) ~[LuckPerms-Bukkit-Legacy-5.4.141.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin.setEnabled(JavaPlugin.java:291) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginInstanceManager.disablePlugin(PaperPluginInstanceManager.java:237) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.disablePlugin(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:114) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.disablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:550) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginInstanceManager.enablePlugin(PaperPluginInstanceManager.java:206) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at io.papermc.paper.plugin.manager.PaperPluginManagerImpl.enablePlugin(PaperPluginManagerImpl.java:109) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.enablePlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:520) ~[paper-mojangapi-1.21.1-R0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugin(CraftServer.java:640) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.CraftServer.enablePlugins(CraftServer.java:589) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at net.minecraft.server.dedicated.DedicatedServer.initServer(DedicatedServer.java:293) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.runServer(MinecraftServer.java:1215) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at net.minecraft.server.MinecraftServer.lambda$spin$0(MinecraftServer.java:330) ~[paper-1.21.1.jar:1.21.1-69-925c3b9]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[?:?]


В вашем логе четко написано, краш происходит из-за плагина LuckyPerms, используется слишком старая версия, обновите плагин до последней версии или ядро и тогда все заработает.

[17:08:19 ERROR]: Error occurred while enabling LuckPerms v5.4.141 (Is it up to date?)

